# Is there way I can get audio duration while uploading file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

**Html file : code for selecting mp3 file**

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <label> Audio</label>
  <input class="center" id="musicFile" type="file" ngf-select
         ng-model="musicFile" name="file" accept=".mp3,audio/*" required>
</div>
```

**Angularjs code**

```
$scope.files = [];
$scope.audioFileURL = [];
$scope.audioFile = $scope.files.concat(document.getElementById('musicFile').files[0]);
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("musicFile").files[0].duration` ?